# How do I set up global Environment Variables in Garuda Linux?

Tags: android, react-native, environment-variables, archlinux

I recently switched to Garuda Linux and was trying to set-up development environment for react-native. I just wanted to know how do I export my `ANDROID_HOME` within `.baschrc` for global environment variables. It uses pacman as package manager.
I'm a total new to any Linux environment and I don't know anything about it's file system and commands.
And yes I searched and tried almost all the methods I could find on this topic. I also asked this in the Garuda Forum but they just closed my topic without properly answering. I cannot seem to find what exactly I'm doing wrong. Please help and guide me through the steps.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add these lines to one of your environment configs:

```py
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/your/android/sdk # change this
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

The specific config will depend on how global you want it to be and how your configs are sourced, but in general:

- [Global variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/environment_variables#Globally): `/etc/profile`
- [User variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/environment_variables#Per_user): `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

Garuda uses `fish` by default. You can save your path in `config.fish`.
For example, if I want to export environment variable for PHP, then I will have to write

`set PATH $PATH /opt/lampp/bin:$PATH`

And then paste this code to file `config.fish`.
You can also paste code in `~/.profile.` as fish's config is automatically set to read `~/.profile`.

Similarly for android, it will  probably like
`set ANDROID_HOME ~/.android # /opt/android-sdk`

Also check out the [fish docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#startup-where-s-bashrc) & https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#variables-export for more details.

Source - https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/how-to-add-set-enviroment-variables-or-paths-in-garuda/8777

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Environment variable in the system. well, you can use the above example. Here I am trying a different approach.

open terminal

```sh
sudo nano ~./bashrc
```

Save your variable in the file and save it.

```
# .bashrc file
export VAR="My permanent variable"
```

That's it